# Jquery Slider spacing fubar on ie7 and i6

Tags: jquery, html, css

So ive been trying to debug this friggin spacing issue for the last 4 hours.. and I cant friggin solve it!!!

If you go to http://myurbanlunchbox.com you will see right away what I am refering to.  The image slider has spacing issues, but only in IE6 and IE7.. (as usual).

Can anyone point out where im going wrong?

Comment: BTW - it's missing the vertical bar in IE6 that separates the image from the right hand title section. A z-index issue perhaps?

Comment: You can also see that issue in IE8 when in "compatibility mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the slider which is messing up.  Rather, IE isn't displaying the right border of #slider.  I think moving the border to #overview would provide the style you're looking for.  I have no idea why IE is messing up the border.